# Application of l'Hopital's Rule in a past paper

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In an old exam paper the following solution is given:

$$\lim_{r \to 0}\cfrac{\sin\left(\cfrac{\mu_1\cdot r}{R}\right)}{\mu_1\cfrac{r}{R}}\overset{l'Hopital}{=}\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{R}\cos\left(\cfrac{\mu_1\cdot r}{R}\right)}{\mu_1\cfrac{1}{R}}=\frac{1}{\mu_1}$$

My understanding of l'Hopital is that the result should be $1$:

$$\lim_{r \to 0}\cfrac{\sin\left(\cfrac{\mu_1\cdot r}{R}\right)}{\mu_1\cfrac{r}{R}}=\cfrac{\cfrac{\mu_1}{R}\cos\left(\cfrac{\mu_1\cdot r}{R}\right)}{\mu_1\cfrac{1}{R}}=1$$

Is this a mistake or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: No, you have not.  The exam solution has incorrectly differentiated the numerator and left out the $μ_1$ term.

Comment: If $\mu_1$ is a constant not depending on $r$, you are definitely right as the derivative of the composite function $\sin(\frac{\mu_1 r}{R})$ is $\frac{\mu_1}{R}\cos(\frac{\mu_1 r}{R})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. One might also substitute $\frac{\mu_1r}{R}=: h$ and then ends up with $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}h=1$